# Application name in kivy

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I have two applications with one kv file. Between both  applications is different only in app class name. Application A gives good result, but application B is bad. Where is problem?

application A:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.5')
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.app import App

class MyW(GridLayout):
    pass

class ShowApp(App):
def build(self):
    Builder.load_file('d:\\MyPgm\\Python\\kivy\\ControlShow    \\ControlShow.kv')
    return MyW()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ShowApp().run()
```

application B:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.5')
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.app import App

class MyW(GridLayout):
    pass

class ControlShowApp(App):
def build(self):
    Builder.load_file('d:\\MyPgm\\Python\\kivy\\ControlShow    \\ControlShow.kv')
    return MyW()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ControlShowApp().run()
```

KV file:

```
<MyW>
    cols: 2
    rows: 2
    Button:
      id: label1
      text: 'B1'
    Button:
      id: label2
      text: 'B2'
    Button:
      id: label3
      text: 'B3'
    Button:
      id: label4
      text: 'B4'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems are as follow:

1. A class rule, declared by the name of a widget class between < > and followed by : e.g. <MyW>:
2. The indentation is 4 spaces

## Example

### ControlShow.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<MyW>:
    cols: 2
    rows: 2
    Button:
        id: label1
        text: 'B1'
    Button:
        id: label2
        text: 'B2'
    Button:
        id: label3
        text: 'B3'
    Button:
        id: label4
        text: 'B4'
```

### ShowApp.py

```
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.app import App


class MyW(GridLayout):
    pass


class ShowApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_file('d:\\MyPgm\\Python\\kivy\\ControlShow    \\ControlShow.kv')
        return MyW()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ShowApp().run()
```

### ControlShowApp.py

```
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.app import App


class MyW(GridLayout):
    pass


class ControlShowApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_file('d:\\MyPgm\\Python\\kivy\\ControlShow    \\ControlShow.kv')
        return MyW()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ControlShowApp().run()
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank You very much

Comment: Hi ikolim, I tested next application (I observed rules from your answer) and my problems are similar to problems from qustions. Can you help me via e-mail? Thank you jasan